# Payment (Payment Connect) records are not getting created in Sandbox

Tags: auth

We are using Payment connect to process and manage credit card payments. Recently we did sandbox refresh from Production and after that the Payment records are not getting created in Sandbox but are getting created in Production. Payment Connect settings looks same in in both Production and Sandbox. I am using Payment Connect to connect Salesforce to Authorize.Net.

PaymentConnect is a Salesforce appExchange product by Linvio used for Payment management and Credit card processing. Through custom code we are calling Authorize.Net service and this service in turn creates Payment record in salesforce. Whoever has used PaymentConnect may be able help me resolve this issue.
Any help/suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you backup the settings before you refreshed the sandbox? It's likely there is a url there that points to a sandbox for Authorize.Net that got overwritten with the production url.

Comment: @martin, are you mentioning about the "relay script" field. In this field we have configured one url and its same as the earlier one (before sandbox refresh).

Comment: did u try enabling the logs in Prod and sandbox and then compare? To see why it is working differently

Comment: Yeah, I tried comparing sandbox and Production logs but looking same...